# Spring- Difference and use case @Repository and @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I started to use spring boot I was annotating my interface with `@Repository`all these days I was following the same, but today I happened to come across annotating with another way called `@RepositoryRestResource`. What is the difference between them, When is it used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@RepositoryRestResource` means you have REST endpoint to the repository. So user calls it directly via REST calls.

`@Repository` is a marker to a component which somehow stores data (CRUD operations). It is not necessary be accessible from external users directly.

So in case of `@RepositoryRestResource` you don't have any controller/service/dao layers but direct access.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer mentioned above, you can also customize your REST endpoints using @RepositoryRestResource.

Comment: Your answer will be much more usefull in case you'll add some links to information you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Repository` annotation enables exception translation so you can handle Springs `DataAccessException` instead of underlying persistence implementation exceptions (via `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`). `@RepositoryRestResource` is not a specialization of `@Repository` so you might want in include both, to expose REST endpoints and enable exception translation.